# Filter an array of objects by the length of the value of a string

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, filter, lodash

want to filter an array of objects by array value of a key.

```js
var data = [
  {
    "name": "Jim",
    "age" : []
  },
  {
    "name": "Jerry",
    "age": [1,2]
  }
];
 var notEmpty = _.filter(data, ['age', null]);
```

would like to have the output of variable `notEmpty` return the object Jerry since the age array is not empty.

Answer (score 2):

Without lodash it would be:

```
  const notEmpty = data.filter(el => el.age.length);
```

Answer (score 2):

Using vanilla javascript, this would give your desired result:

```
data.filter(x => x["age"].length > 0)
```